# makefile to build multiple executables in subdirectories

Tags: makefile

My tree directory is this:

```
projecto
   makefile
   userfolder/
       user.c
   csfolder/
       cs.c
```

My current makefile only works if the .c files are in the same folder. 
How to compile those .c files inside those directory?

```
all: user cs

user: user.c
    gcc -o user user.c

cs: cs.c
    gcc -o CS cs.c
```

Comment: That's a rather broad question. I recommend reading the [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). Yeah, the whole thing; it's long but really good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
all: user cs

userfolder/user: userfolder/user.c
    gcc -o $@ $<

csfolder/CS: csfolder/cs.c
    gcc -o $@ $<
```

And if you study [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), you can write much more general and powerful makefiles.